# Unable to Access Authenticated User in vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, vuex, laravel-passport

I have created an authentication system using laravel passport for an api am building, and everything works when i test it on postman but trying to integrate that into a front end app is where i seem to be having a little headache as postman returns the authenticated user but vue throws a "401 Unauthorized" exception all the time.

the Laravel route is like so:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
    Route::post('me', function (Request $req) {
        return $req->user();
    });
});
```

This works when i try it on postman
[image]

Here is what i have done in vue

**create an Api.js file for custom axios config**

```js
import axios from 'axios';

let Api  = axios.create({
    baseURL: `${window.location.origin}/api`
})

export default Api
```

**create Auth.js file to store authrization methods**

```js
import Api from './Api';

export default {
    register(formData) {
        return Api.post('auth/register', formData)
    },

    login(formData) {
        return Api.post('auth/login', formData)
    }
}
```

**User.js file for store methods that has to do with users**

```js
import Api from './Api';

export default {
    fetchUserData() {
        return Api.post('me');
    }
}
```

**subscriber.js**

```js
import store from "./store";
import axios from "axios";

store.subscribe((mutation) => {
    switch (mutation.type) {
        case "auth/SET_TOKEN":
                if(mutation.payload){
                    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${mutation.payload}`
                }
            break;
    
        default:
            break;
    }
})
```

and in my **auth** module

```js
import Auth from '../../../api/Auth';
import User from '../../../api/User';
import {SET_TOKEN, SET_USER} from '../../mutation-types'

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        token: null,
        user: null,
    },
    mutations: {
        SET_TOKEN (state, token) {
            state.token = token
        },
        SET_USER (state, user) {
            state.user = user
        }
    },
    actions:{
        async userLogin({dispatch}, credentials) {
            let response = await Auth.login(credentials)
            return dispatch('attempt', response.data.access_token)
        },

        async userRegiser({commit}, credentials) {
            let response = await Auth.register(credentials)
            console.log(response.data);
        },

        async attempt({commit}, token) {
            commit(SET_TOKEN, token)

            try {
                let response = await User.fetchUserData()
                console.log(response.data);
                commit(SET_USER, response.data)
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

so when i make a request to the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/me` route using `User.fetchUserData()` i get

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/me 401 (Unauthorized)
dispatchXhrRequest @ app.js:297
xhrAdapter @ app.js:131
dispatchRequest @ app.js:777
Promise.then (async)
request @ app.js:554
Axios.(anonymous function) @ app.js:579
wrap @ app.js:1143
fetchUserData @ app.js:57079
_callee3$ @ app.js:58332
tryCatch @ app.js:37995
invoke @ app.js:38225
(anonymous) @ app.js:38050
asyncGeneratorStep @ app.js:58253
_next @ app.js:58255
(anonymous) @ app.js:58255
(anonymous) @ app.js:58255
attempt @ app.js:58352
wrappedActionHandler @ app.js:56464
dispatch @ app.js:56129
boundDispatch @ app.js:56019
local.dispatch @ app.js:56392
_callee$ @ app.js:58288
tryCatch @ app.js:37995
invoke @ app.js:38225
(anonymous) @ app.js:38050
asyncGeneratorStep @ app.js:58253
_next @ app.js:58255
Promise.then (async)
asyncGeneratorStep @ app.js:58253
_next @ app.js:58255
(anonymous) @ app.js:58255
(anonymous) @ app.js:58255
userLogin @ app.js:58296
wrappedActionHandler @ app.js:56464
dispatch @ app.js:56129
boundDispatch @ app.js:56019
mappedAction @ app.js:56677
submit @ app.js:2430
submit @ app.js:39838
invokeWithErrorHandling @ app.js:45477
invoker @ app.js:45802
original._wrapper @ app.js:51161
app.js:58344 Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (app.js:711)
    at settle (app.js:972)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:180)
```

Comment: did u check if u are getting the token from the api or not before fetching with it?

Comment: yea, the subscriber returns a payload containing the token and i have some other tests to verify and they all return the token

Comment: @mehran i just changed `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/me` route method from POST to GET and it worked.